# Finding the adjoint of a linear operator using Dirac notation.

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Trying to answer this question and I am fairly new to Dirac Notation:

> Let $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ be two states in a Hilbert Space and consider the linear operator $A:=|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|$. Show that the adjoint is given by $A^\dagger=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$.

Here's my go at it.

Using the definition for the adjoint as $$\langle A^{\dagger}x|y\rangle=\langle x| Ay\rangle$$ Using the right side we achieve $\langle x|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|y\rangle$. Now $$\langle x|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|y\rangle=\langle A^{\dagger}x|y\rangle$$ Inputting the given expression for $A^\dagger$ I get $$\langle x|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|y\rangle=\langle|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|x\rangle|y\rangle$$

I am unsure of what happens at $\langle|\phi\rangle$ and can't see how these two equate. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Notice that the dot product is sesquilinear. We then have $\langle A^{\dagger}x|y\rangle=\langle y| A^{\dagger}x\rangle ^*=\langle y| \phi\rangle ^*\langle\psi|x\rangle^*=\langle x| \psi \rangle\langle \phi | y\rangle$, as required.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

The Dirac notation gets sometimes confusing and it may help to write everything using the standard Hilbert space notation (which is almost the same as Dirac's). Now:

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the inner product. Fix $\psi, \varphi \in H$. Define the operator $A: H \to H$ by
$$
Ax = \psi \langle \varphi, x \rangle
$$
and the operator $A^\dagger: H \to H$ by
$$
A^\dagger x = \varphi \langle \psi, x \rangle\,.
$$
Now
$$
\langle x, Ay \rangle = \langle x, \psi \rangle \langle \varphi, y \rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle A^\dagger x, y \rangle = \langle \psi, x \rangle^* \langle \varphi, y \rangle = \langle x, \psi \rangle \langle \varphi, y \rangle\,,
$$
where I assumed that the inner product is linear in the second variable and conjugate-linear in the first variable. Thus $A^\dagger$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $A$.

Edit: The problem with your computation is that you misinterpreted $\langle A^\dagger x|$. Because $| A^\dagger x \rangle = | \phi \rangle \langle \psi | x \rangle $ we get
$$
\langle A^\dagger x| = \langle x | \psi \rangle \langle \phi |\,.
$$

Comment: Is there a name for the operator $A$?

Comment: I am trying to find the polar decomposition of $A$ and I found that $A^{\dagger} A x = \eta \langle \eta, x \rangle$ and therefore $| A | x = \langle \eta, x \rangle$. Is this correct? Because then $$
\xi \langle \eta, x \rangle
= T x
\overset{!}{=} (U | T |)(x)
= U(\eta \langle \eta,x \rangle).
$$ How can I find $U$?

Answer (score 1):

I would use that $\langle x|y\rangle=\langle y|x\rangle^*.$ Hence
$$\langle A^{\dagger}x|y\rangle=\langle y|A^\dagger x\rangle^*=(\langle y|\phi\rangle\langle \psi|x\rangle)^*=\langle y|\phi\rangle^*\langle \psi|x\rangle^*=\langle \phi|y\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle=\langle x|Ay\rangle.$$

---

**Edit.** Since vnd commented before me I will additionaly write some general feature.

If $B=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|,$ then
$$\langle Bx|y\rangle=\langle y|B x\rangle^*=(\langle y|\phi\rangle\langle \psi|x\rangle)^*=\langle y|\phi\rangle^*\langle \psi|x\rangle^*=\langle \phi|y\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle.$$
Hence we can expand Dirac notation to $\langle Bx|y\rangle,$ where $B=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|,$ in such a way that
$$\langle Bx|y\rangle=\langle \phi|y\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle.$$
And since it follows from properties **it is the only reasable way to write it.**